# Los botones no responden

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo 3 botones puestos en un main activity, que me llevan a otros 3 activitis al dar clic sobre ellos. La cosa es que tengo puesto un screen splash que se me pone invisible, cuando el webview ha cargado, es decir, cuando arranco, o paso entre activities, el screen splash sale a modo de pantalla de carga, y cuando ha terminado de cargar, desaparece (invisible). El problema lo tengo en los botones, que al dar clic sobre ellos, si bajo el viewpage, es decir, si lo deslizo la web para abajo no me pillan el clic; en la posición en la que aparecen después del screen splash SÍ funcionan, pero si luego navego por la web, por ejemplo, bajando hacia abajo de la web NO me pillan el clic, ¿se debe al código JAVS, XML...? Adjunto código para ver si alguien me puede ayudar. Muchas gracias.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/spscreen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/pikachu2"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/> -->

<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="411dp"
    android:layout_height="670dp"
    android:src="@drawable/gifprueba"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-3dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="426dp"
    android:layout_height="754dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-3dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-8dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hgallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_x="500dp"
        android:layout_y="550dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_gallery"
        android:text="Gall"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="0dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hnews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_home"
        android:text="News"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="0dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="141dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hcontact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_x="150dp"
        android:layout_y="150dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_news"
        android:text="Cont"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="0dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="277dp" />

</WebView>
```

```
package com.example.myapplication1landa;
```

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView view;
    private ImageView splashScreen;
    private Button btG;
    private Button btN;
    private Button btC;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    splashScreen = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.test);

    btG = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.hgallery);

    btG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(View v) {

                                   Intent bt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main1Activity.class);
                                   startActivity(bt);
                               }
                           }

    );

    btN = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.hnews);

    btN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(View v) {

                                   Intent bt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                                   startActivity(bt);
                               }
                           }

    );

    btC = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.hcontact);

    btC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent bt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(bt);
        }
                          }

    );

    String url = "http://google.es/";
    view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // do your stuff here
            splashScreen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    WebSettings s = view.getSettings();
    s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    s.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    view.loadUrl(url);
}
```

}

Comment: No entiendo muy bien. ¿Tienes los botones dentro del `WebView`? ¿Por qué ahí y no en el layout de la Activity, on el Toolbar o en una barra inferior?

Comment: Hola Cedano. ¿Cómo me sugerirías que lo pusiera? Lo que ocurre es que me carga el splash screen y los botones dejan de funcionar al mover algo del webview, como al darle a bajar la web.

Comment: Esos botones parecen ser parte de otra cosa, algo así como un menú. Lo correcto sería que los pusieras en el Toolbar, sea directamente, o por ejemplo como forma de menú (los tres puntitos verticales) en la parte superior derecha. No veo por qué tengas que ponerlos en el WebView ¿?

Comment: Los he metido dentro de una toolbar, pero si los saco del webview, me desaparecen al desaparecer el screen splash. ¿Sabrías cómo puedo solventar este problema?

Comment: No sé que es eso del *screen splash*  que mencionas o para qué tienes eso, ¿sirve para algo ese tal *screen splash*? El Toolbar parmanece siempre, mientras dure la actividad y sirve precisamente para poner en él aquellas cosas que podrías necesitar en cualquier momento. Por ejemplo si esos botones te son útiles en cualquier momento, es ahí donde deberían estar y no en el `WebView`, porque en el WebView te vas a desplazar y luego no sabrás que hacer con los botones, además si los metes en el WebView molestarían para leer el contenido de la vista. ¿No es un problema de orden el tuyo?